# Dynamic Ids in a Collapsible List Group

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

New to web development and having a few issues with something I thought would be fairly straightforward...I guess it never is!

What I'm trying to do is create a collapsible list group from a dynamic list and I'm having issues binding the header selected by the user to the list of items.

The collapsible list should look something like this, with selection of the street name showing/hiding the property details (number, people staying)

- Street ABC

  - House Number 1
  - People Staying 2
  - House Number 2
  - People Staying 3
- Street XYZ

  - House Number 1
  - People Staying 4
  - House Number 2
  - People Staying 5

Shown below is my view model

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public List<Street> Streets { get; set; }
}


public class Street
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public List<Property> Properties { get; set; }
}

public class Property
{
    public Int32 Number { get; set; }
    public Int32 PeopleStaying { get; set; }
}
```

My html at the moment is shown below with the 'href' and 'id' attributes hard coded to "collapse1" so on every street selection the first street is shown:

```
            <div class="panel-group">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Streets</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    @foreach (var street in Model.Streets)
                    {
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">@street.Name</a>
                        <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                            @foreach (var house in street.Properties)
                            {
                                <ul class="list-group">
                                    <li class="list-group-item">@house.Number</li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item">@house.PeopleStaying</li>
                                </ul>
                            }
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

So the question is, is it possible to make the href/id dynamic such that any number of streets and properties can be displayed?

Comment: Add an incremented variable, maybe? `var i = 0`, and then increment it inside the loop: `i++`. Use the variable to concatenate the `div` id, creating `collapse1`, `collapse2`, `collapse3`... and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@{var i=0;}
@foreach (var street in Model.Streets)
{
    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-@i">@street.Name</a>
    <div id="collapse-@(i++)" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        @foreach (var house in street.Properties)
        {
            <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item">@house.Number</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">@house.PeopleStaying</li>
             </ul>
        }
    </div>
}
```